Common chart X-axis in Power BI for datasets with no relationship
A newbie question.
I have two tables (CoreData and ExtendedData) in Power BI both of which have (only) a relationship to a Staff table (each with Cross-filter direction = Both).
Both have a SessionNumber column (int) which represents the nth meeting at which data was collected from a meeting of project beneficiaries:
CoreData



SessionNumber
LoggedByStaffMemberId
NumberOfDistributions




1
1
10


2
2
20


4
2
30


5
1
40


6
2
50



ExtendedData



SessionNumber
LoggedByStaffMemberId
NumberOfTrainingAttendees




1
3
5


2
4
15


3
3
25


5
3
35


6
4
45



Staff



StaffMemberId
Name




1
Bob


2
Jane


3
Fred


4
Claire



Relationships as follows:

I'd like to be able to plot the NumberOfDistributions column from CoreData and NumberOfTrainingAttendees from ExtendedData, together on a line chart - using the same x-axis (SessionNumber, running from 1 upwards).
I only seem to be able to choose CoreData.SessionNumber OR ExtendedData.SessionNumber as the x-axis.  If I add in both then I see all permutations of the session numbers from both tables along the bottom.
I really want to be able to define a shared x-axis as a continuous axis from 1 up to the maximum of CoreData.SessionNumber or ExtendedData.SessionNumber, and plot the values from the two tables together.
Any suggestions would be very welcome.

You need to create a common dimension table in power query or DAX. Can you post your sample tables as markdown so they can be copied?

Thanks @davidebacci .  The problem with doing that is that I already have relationships defined between CoreData and ExtendedData and another fact table (where cross-filter direction = Both).  When I try to create a relationship with this new common dimension table, I get the error "There are ambiguous paths between..."

This is a data modelling question and it is impossible to help without seeing the full model. You shouldn't connect fact tables (they sound like a single fact table to me) and you should avoid bi-directional filters if you're not 100% sure what  you're doing.

Thanks again @davidebacci.  I have added in to the original post a simplified version of the table structure.  I also meant to say in my previous comment that relationships are defined between CoreData and ExtendedData and another dimension table (i.e. Staff).  Apologies - a software dev by trade but very new to the world of PBI and data warehouse terminology!

Thanks. I think we need a screenshot of your existing data model too so we can see which relationships you have.

Your ongoing guidance is much appreciated, @davidebacci !  Relationship screenshot now added

If you change your bi-directional relationships to uni-directional, can you then add your new dimension table?
